Localization of profinite integers
Let $p$ be a prime number, $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at $p$ and $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} = \prod_{q\text{ prime}} \mathbb{Z}_q$ the profinite completion of the integers. Is the abelian group $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$?
We certainly have $\mathbb{Z}_q \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ or trivial whether or not $p = q$, but the tensor product does not distribute over the infinite product in general. We also have a natural surjective map $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_{(p)} \to \mathbb{Z}_p$ induced by the projection on the $p$-th coordinate. Can it fail to be injective?
EDIT: I just realized that $\mathbb{Z}_q \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is very far from trivial in general. We can consider the multiplication map $\mathbb{Z}_q \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_{(p)} \to \mathbb{Q}_q$, and it is surjective since it's image is a subring containing $\mathbb{Z}_q$ and $1/q$. It is also injective since any element of $\mathbb{Z}_q \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ can be written as $x \otimes q^{-i}$ for some $x \in \mathbb{Z}_q$ and $i \geq 0$. Hence, it's more likely that $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ be isomorphic to something like $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \prod_{q \neq p} \mathbb{Q}_q$, where we are taking some form of restricted product on the right hand side.
